# diff - if file contains a number greater than x, then

Tags: bash, awk

Not sure how to do this -- I have a file that contains one line with one number in it.

If that number ever goes above, say, 3 - I need it to e-mail me.

I have been mucking around with awk, but can't get the syntax right.

Sorry for my amateurishness !

the awk command I have is thus:

```
awk '$1>3' diff.txt
```

That returns the number in the file, so long as it's greater than 3. My guess is that I tell it to do something *if* it prints output. If the number is 3 or less, it prints nothing - and I don't need it to do anything.

Something like

```
if awk '$1>3' diff.txt >/dev/null ; then
echo Take action!
else
echo All OK!
fi
```

I don't know how to correctly format the awk command into the script, it isn't work. But I suspect I'm on the right track.

There's probably some better solution anyway.

Thanks!
Steve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are thousand different ways to do it but if you want it with `awk`, that is it:

```
awk '
{
  if ($1 > 3) { 
      system("echo Take action") }
  else { 
      system("echo  All ok") 
  }
}' < diff.txt
```

`system` is here how you start external program from `awk`.
Of course if you only want to print something you just write `print`, not `system`.

Comment: yeah, i guessed there are a million ways to do it. i don't have the experience. thanks igor!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need awk here. Just read will be enough:

```
read -r num < diff.txt
if [[ "$num" -gt 3 ]]; then
   echo "Take action!"
else
   echo "All OK!"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Your if line is checking the exit status of the command not whether it created any output. You need your awk script to exit with a success/failure exit status depending on the contents it finds. Do that and your if will work. To do that you want to use the awk `exit` command. The shell `!` is to invert the awk 0=false/1=true to the shell's 0=true/1=false.

```
if ! awk '{exit $1>3}' diff.txt; then
    echo "Take action!"
else
    echo "All OK!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this particular method:

```
(( $(<file) > 3 )) && mailx -s "File contains $(<file)..." me@whereever.org < /dev/null
```